# Logstash failed to establish a connection with elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, logstash

I am trying to collect the logs from kubernetes pods and pass it to elastic db using logstash and filebeats.I am able to deploy the Elasticsearch and kibana in k8 cluster but i am not able to deploy my logstash and filebeat.

My elastisearch.yaml file is

```
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
name: elasticsearch
spec:
version: 7.14.1 #Make sure you use the version of your choice
http:
service:
spec:
type: LoadBalancer #Adds a External IP
nodeSets:

name: default
count: 1
config:
node.store.allow_mmap: false
```

Logstash.yaml file is

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
name: logstash-configmap
data:
logstash.yml: |
http.host: "0.0.0.0"
path.config: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
logstash.conf: |
input {
beats {
port => 5044
}
}
output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => "https://External ip:9200"
index =>"testlogs"
user => "elastic"
password => "xxxx"
cacert => "/etc/"
ssl_certificate_verification => false
}
}
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
name: logstash-deployment
spec:
replicas: 1
selector:
matchLabels:
app: logstash
template:
metadata:
labels:
app: logstash
spec:
containers:
- name: logstash
image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.14.1
ports:
- containerPort: 5044
volumeMounts:
- name: config-volume
mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/config
- name: logstash-pipeline-volume
mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
volumes:
- name: config-volume
configMap:
name: logstash-configmap
items:
- key: logstash.yml
path: logstash.yml
- name: logstash-pipeline-volume
configMap:
name: logstash-configmap
items:
- key: logstash.conf
path: logstash.conf
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
name: logstash-service
spec:
selector:
app: logstash
ports:
- protocol: TCP
port: 5044
targetPort: 5044
```

After deploying my logstash pods got crashed and getting this error

```
[ERROR] 2022-10-21 08:54:16.937 [[main]-pipeline-manager] javapipeline - Pipeline error {:pipeline_id=>"main", :exception=>#<Errno::EISDIR: Is a directory - channel: org.jruby.util.io.ChannelFD@2f88e4ba /etc/>, :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/manticore-0.7.1-java/lib/manticore/client.rb:642:in block in setup_trust_store'", "org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1158:in open'", "org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:317:in open'", "uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/open-uri.rb:37:in open'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/manticore-0.7.1-java/lib/manticore/client.rb:641:in setup_trust_store'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/manticore-0.7.1-java/lib/manticore/client.rb:629:in ssl_socket_factory_from_options'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/manticore-0.7.1-java/lib/manticore/client.rb:396:in pool_builder'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/manticore-0.7.1-java/lib/manticore/client.rb:404:in pool'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/manticore-0.7.1-java/lib/manticore/client.rb:207:in initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-11.0.3-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/manticore_adapter.rb:26:in initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-11.0.3-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb:319:in build_adapter'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-11.0.3-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb:323:in build_pool'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-11.0.3-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb:62:in initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-11.0.3-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client_builder.rb:106:in create_http_client'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-11.0.3-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client_builder.rb:102:in build'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-11.0.3-java/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/elasticsearch/common.rb:34:in build_client'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-11.0.3-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch.rb:275:in register'", "org/logstash/config/ir/compiler/OutputStrategyExt.java:131:in register'", "org/logstash/config/ir/compiler/AbstractOutputDelegatorExt.java:68:in register'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:228:in block in register_plugins'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1820:in each'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:227:in register_plugins'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:585:in maybe_setup_out_plugins'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:240:in start_workers'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:185:in run'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:137:in block in start'"], "pipeline.sources"=>["/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x5b2f9d8f@/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:125 run>"}
[INFO ] 2022-10-21 08:54:16.940 [[main]-pipeline-manager] javapipeline - Pipeline terminated {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
[ERROR] 2022-10-21 08:54:16.957 [Converge PipelineAction::Create] agent - Failed to execute action {:id=>:main, :action_type=>LogStash::ConvergeResult::FailedAction, :message=>"Could not execute action: PipelineAction::Create, action_result: false", :backtrace=>nil}
```

Is it because of the ca certificate path which i have mentioned?If so can someone share the correct way to mention the ca certificate and where do i find it in k8 cluster. Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 2):

If you check the [documentation of the Elasticsearch Output Plugin of Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-cacert), ca_cert is expected to be a valid file on the file_system not a directory.

You are currently using ECK to manage Elasticsearch and Kibana. ECK creates for you several kubernetes secrets including the certificate_authority of Elasticsearch.

You can get a list of secret with the command `kubectl get secret` and search for a secret named after your Elasticsearch Cluster name (i.e., `elasticsearch`) and with the suffix "-remote-ca", in your case it should be `elasticsearch-remote-ca`.

You can check the content of the secret with `kubectl get secret elasticsearch-remote-ca -o json`. You are interested in the json path `data > ca.crt`. This string is base64 encoded, thus to obtain a valid certificate you should decode it.

Fortunately, kubectl supports also [go-template](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#pkg-overview) as an output format, which allow us to write this one liner command to extract the key .data.ca.crt and decode it without external dependencies:

```
kubectl get secret tiny-es-remote-ca -o go-template='{{index .data "ca.crt" | base64decode}}'
```

This will output a valid ca certificate something like:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDOzCCA....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

We can now copy the certificate into a file named ca.pem.

Now, we can mount this file in the pod and use it in the configuration.

Comment: i am trying from a windows 10 machine. If i am giving this command in my cmd "kubectl get secret <my-development>-es-remote-ca -n development -o json | jq '.data["ca.crt"]' -r | base64 -d > ca_file.pem" i am getting the error for jq and base64                                           'jq' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file..How to resolve this

Comment: Also if i give the filename in cacert path in yaml file am getting the error as  "Invalid setting for elasticsearch output plugin:
      # This setting must be a path  cacert => "/etc/ca_file.pem"

Comment: Hi psp. Please I edited my question to be platform-independent. JQ (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is a bash command to extract jsonpath expressions from json object, which is not installed in Windows by default. About your last comment. ca_file.pem was empty, thus is not a valid cacert.